# python create an arbitrary score based off certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas, expression, formula

I want to create a formula that will create an arbitrary score based on certain variables. For example, given a dataframe with the following columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Joe', 'Bob'], 'Score': [0.75, 0.8], 'Length': [10, 20]})
```

I want to create a new column, `Result`, based off the following criteria, ***In this order of importance***

1. `Length` closest to 10 has the most weight
2. The highest `score` has the most weight
3. 'Bob' has more weight than 'Joe'

Some more info:

- Opt. assume that there are more than 2 `names`, with an option to specify which names are more important than the others
- `Score` is a decimal from 0 to 1
- `Length` is an int from 1-200

Basically, I am having trouble coming up with a function that captures these desires weights/importances. What would such a function look like?

Comment: Please provide a such list of weight for names.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a temporary DataFrame with custom columns to sort and use its index to reorder the original:

```
idx = (df
  .assign(Length=-df['Length'].sub(10).abs(),
          Name=pd.Categorical(df['Name'], categories=['Joe', 'Bob'], ordered=True)
          )
  .sort_values(by=['Length', 'Score', 'Name'], ascending=False)
  .index
)

# reorder values based on priority
sorted_df = df.loc[idx]
```

Alternative if only some names have a priority:

```
d = {'Bob': 2}
# in the assign of the previous code
#.assign(
  Name=df['Name'].map(d).fillna(0)
#)
```

If you want to add a rank instead of sorting:

```
df.loc[idx, 'rank'] = range(len(df))
```

Comment: *NB. I couldn't test the code, so I can't exclude a typo/oversight.*

Comment: Your code works well. I have exactly the same answer 0_o

Comment: @Corralien thanks, I'm always reluctant to post untested code straight out of my head :p